# How to test dependency has been called correctly

Tags: go, testing, dependency-injection

In Go, how would I test that a mock dependency has been called in the correct way.

If I have a struct that takes a interface for a dependency, after injection I want to be able to test the original mock object has been called.

My current code in this example I can not see that the struct value has changed. If I change my code to pass by reference it triggers the error:

*s.simpleInterface.Call undefined (type *SimpleInterface is pointer to interface, not interface)*

```
type SimpleInterface interface {
    Call()
}

type Simple struct {
    simpleInterface SimpleInterface
}

func (s Simple) CallInterface() {
    s.simpleInterface.Call()
}

type MockSimple struct {
    hasBeenCalled bool
}

func (ms MockSimple) Call() {
    ms.hasBeenCalled = true
}

func TestMockCalled(t *testing.T) {
    ms := MockSimple{}
    s := Simple{
        simpleInterface: ms,
    }
    s.CallInterface()

    if ms.hasBeenCalled != true {
        t.Error("Interface has not been called")
    }
}
```

Comment: Always use a *pointer receiver* whenever your method is supposed to change the state of that receiver. i.e. `func (ms *MockSimple) Call() {`. If you don't, then the changes to `ms` will not be visible outside the method's body because `ms` is actually a copy of the instance on which the method has been called, it is not the instance itself. This change will also require that you use a `MockSimple` pointer to set `Simple.simpleInterface`. i.e. `Simple{simpleInterface: &ms}`.

Comment: I tried this out and started getting the error of MockSimple does not implement SimpleInterface (Call method has pointer receiver)

Comment: That's why you need to apply the change mentioned in the last sentence of my previous comment.

Comment: Try switching the commented line here: https://play.golang.com/p/3FZwgT4Vhjs. One compiles the other doesn't.

Comment: Ah yes apologies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three easy ways to fix this:

1- Change the signature of the Call method to receive a pointer to MockSimple, and when instantiating the Simple struct, give it the address of your mock:

```
func (ms *MockSimple) Call() {
    ms.hasBeenCalled = true
}

func TestMockCalled(t *testing.T) {
    ms := MockSimple{}
    s := Simple{
        simpleInterface: &ms,
    }
    s.CallInterface()

    if ms.hasBeenCalled != true {
        t.Error("Interface has not been called")
    }
}
```

2- Not the cleanest solution, but still works. Use it if you really cant use #1. Declare "hasBeenCalled" somewhere else and change your MockSimple to hold a pointer to it:

```
type MockSimple struct {
    hasBeenCalled *bool
}

func (ms MockSimple) Call() {
    *ms.hasBeenCalled = true
}

func TestMockCalled(t *testing.T) {
    hasBeenCalled := false
    ms := MockSimple{&hasBeenCalled}
    s := Simple{
        simpleInterface: ms,
    }
    s.CallInterface()

    if hasBeenCalled != true {
        t.Error("Interface has not been called")
    }
}
```

3- Probably a **really bad solution**: using globals, so I would only use it as a last resort (always avoid global state). Make "hasBeenCalled" a global and modify it from the method.

```
var hasBeenCalled bool

type MockSimple struct{}

func (ms MockSimple) Call() {
    hasBeenCalled = true
}

func TestMockCalled(t *testing.T) {
    ms := MockSimple{}
    s := Simple{
        simpleInterface: ms,
    }
    s.CallInterface()

    if hasBeenCalled != true {
        t.Error("Interface has not been called")
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: As above the first solution starts raising the error MockSimple does not implement SimpleInterface (Call method has pointer receiver)

Comment: Your second solution was the best implementation

Comment: @CharlesBryant you really should use the 1st solution, if you prepend `&` before `ms` when setting the `simpleInterface` field you won't get the error that you're claiming you are getting. Solutions 2 and 3 are both unconventional and have no advantage over 1.